# jQuery animation - inconsistent after first run

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I have a list of images that float alongside each other and some links to javascript calls at the top of the page. On clicking a link, all visible images should shrink and vanish and the selected items then expand out and become visible.

This works fine the first time. However, subsequent changes in the selection give unpredicatable results with the fading not always happening.

I've created a [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ChrisFelstead/msb9p/9/) which better shows the issue. Any help is great appreciated.

Chris.

Comment: im not sure what exactly it is supposed to do. what for example is supposed to happen if you click on the 'One' link?

Comment: It works correctly during the first run. The links are basically content filters (working correctly). What doesn't work is the transition animation after the first run. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that animations are run on each element individually, as are the callbacks. So  `showList` is running 15 times.

One way around this is to use a count to track when the last animation has run. For example:

```
function collapseList(selectedFilter) {
    var els = $('.listItem'),
        count = els.length;

    els.animate({
        opacity: 0,
        width: "0px",
        height: "0px"
    }, 2000, function() {
        if ( !--count ) {
          els.hide();
          showList(selectedFilter);
        }
    });
}
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/msb9p/11/

Comment: Thanks. That fixed it. I read about the animations but couldn't see the impact.